# How to code datasource for a NSComboBoxCell with in a Tableview for a macOS program using Xcode 12?

Tags: macos, appkit

I have a test app with a tableView that has a comboBoxCell for one of the columns in Xcode 12:

```
The view controller code is as follows:

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ComboBoxExample
//
//

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSComboBoxCellDataSource {
    var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware",
                  "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky",
                  "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi",
                  "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico",
                  "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania",
                  "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont",
                  "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]
    // var itemCombo: NSComboBoxCellDataSource? = states
    @IBOutlet weak var itemComboCell: NSComboBoxCell!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        itemComboCell.usesDataSource = true
        itemComboCell.dataSource = self
        self.itemComboCell.completes = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    func numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell(in comboBoxCell: NSComboBoxCell) -> Int {
      // anArray is an Array variable containing the objects
        return states.count
    }
    func comboBoxCell(_ comboBoxCell: NSComboBoxCell, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any {
        return (states[index])
    }

}
```

When running the example I get the following error:
2021-03-05 15:16:29.940373-0600 ComboBoxExample[40515:1914724] *** Illegal NSComboBoxCell data source (<ComboBoxExample.ViewController: 0x600000e501b0>).  Must implement numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell: and comboBoxCell:objectValueForItemAtIndex:

What am I doing wrong trying to set the datasource with the following:
itemComboCell.dataSource = self

thanks

Below is an image of the storyboard of this test app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Axk.png)

Comment: Is the table view cell based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell:(NSComboBoxCell *)comboBoxCell;
```

is in Swift

```
optional func numberOfItems(in comboBoxCell: NSComboBoxCell) -> Int
```

Source: [numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscomboboxcelldatasource/1410302-numberofitems)

Comment: I changed numberOfItemsInComboBoxCell function to numberOfItems and the error went away but it still does not work. Also the function comboBoxCell never gets called when I put a break point on it. I must sill be missing something.

Comment: Is the table view cell based?

Comment: I tried your code and the `NSComboBoxCellDataSource` methods are called. The cell based table view isn't maintained and is getting buggy. Consider replacing it by a view based table view.

Comment: thanks, Yes I read that about the cell based tableview had been deprecated so I changed it to view based yesterday and I am working on this. Initially, the IB changed the tableView to cell based when I added the comboBox as a column.